# extract a text contained within a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a requirement to find and extract a text contained within a string.

for example this string :

ITB Z606130000, Richardson Highway MP 80-82 Resurfacing & Drainage Improvements

i just wants to remove ITB z606130000.

Comment: Why don't you just split on comma and retain the second portion?

Comment: show us what you  have tried

Comment: From your example it´s impossible to guess how your structure actually is. Are the entries all starting with `ITB Z606130000` or just seperated by comma or what else is your logic? Anyway we´re not willing to do your work, which is to provide some own affords and ideas and the specific problems you have with your solution. Don´t expect *us* to do *your* work.

Comment: sometimes the comma isn't there so i cant even substring it.. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: is there any solution like i can substring from the 0 that would b a digit..? where i can substring with digit..?

Comment: Could you try writing that comment or your question again with more/better examples? Why does your example have a comma if your data doesn't always? What is the deciding criteria for the front portion you want to remove?

Answer (score 0):

As per **the only example you provided**, this pattern will acquire the `ITB Z606130000` whether there is a comma or not.

```
^[A-Z]+\sZ\d+
```

We specify to only look at the beginning of the string `^` then to match *only* upper case letters `[A-Z]` and that there *will be* one `+` of those letters from that set. Followed by a space `\s` the capital `Z` and the multiple following numbers `\d+`.